# Inductive vs deductive Inference

Tags: inference, causality, philosophical

I am curious to know exactly, what are the (possible) differences between inductive and deductive statistical inferences in applied statistics.

Suggestions for some good resources to learn their differences, pros and cons properly are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there such a thing as deductive statistical inference? I thought statistics was almost by definition in the camp of inductive inference, as far as knowledge gathering goes.